# Swift - Execute multiple commands as root without asking password multiple times

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to write a litte program that checks a couple of directories as root.
I use the following code:

```
func execute(sudoCommands: String) -> String {
    return(execute(command: "osascript -e \"do shell script \\\"" + sudoCommands + "\\\" with administrator privileges\""))
}

func execute(command: String) -> String {
    var arguments:[String] = []
    arguments.append("-c")
    arguments.append( command )

    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
    task.arguments = arguments

    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.standardError = pipe
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()

    return(NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String)
}

func getSize(path: String, asRoot: Bool = false) -> String {

    var result: String!

    if(asRoot){
        result = execute(sudoCommands: "sudo du -shm " + path)
    } else {
        result = execute(command: "du -shm " + path)
    }

    var sizesMB = 0
    for dirResult in result.components(separatedBy: "\n") where dirResult != "" {
        let currentDirSize = dirResult.components(separatedBy: "\t")[0]
        sizesMB = sizesMB + Int(currentDirSize)!
    }

return( "\(sizesMB) MB")
}
```

But if I run `getSize("/Library/Caches/", asRoot: True)` multiple times in a row, it (osascript) will always ask for my password again and again...

Is there some way (that's secure) to execute the commands as root without being prompt to enter the password?
I could ask for the password, save it in a variable and use it when necessary, but that really isn't safe or secure and I rather let Apple handle this one for me...

Comment: There is usually a time period after using `sudo` that you don't have to enter your password. Wouldn't that solve your problem?

Comment: There is a 5 minute time window, but this doesn't count in my case (every command is a new Process).

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: @Natanel I ended up combining all commands with `&&`: 'sudo command1 && command2` But I guess you can doe `sudo command1; command2` too in this context.